# How to save a directory and folder path generated in tkinter to a module that can be called by other py scripts

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI that asks the user to select a directory and name a folder that will be in that directory. In the GUI that destination can be used with ease (now).

I would like to use this location in other py scripts that currently have files sent to absolute paths. Can I make it a module that can be called? I've tried to do that and it's not working. I get an error that the module doesn't exist. The module being mygui.

This is the code in tkinter to get the directory and folder.

```
def selectPath():   
    path_ = askdirectory()
    path.set(path_)
    return path_
        
def create_subfolder():  
    print("folder_name: ", folder.get())
    print("path_name: ", path.get())
    dirs = os.path.join(path.get(), folder.get())
    if not os.path.exists(dirs):
        os.makedirs(dirs)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Tips:','Folder name created successfully!')
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Tips','The folder name exists, please change it')  
    return dirs
```

I am able to send files to the destination (shown below)in the GUI. I would like to do the same outside the GUI

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(filename2, delimiter='\t')
    **destination =  os.path.join(path.get(), folder.get(),**'all_tune_recent_DQ.xlsx')
    df2.to_excel(destination,index=False)
```

For example, maybe something like this?

```
Import mygui

destination2 = mygui.destination.get()

dataframe.to_csv(str(destination2 + datetime.date.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y') + '_Sequence_File_Rack_B.txt'), date_format ='%m-%d-%Y', sep='\t',index=False)
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you use this module in other script? It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Hi acw, I edited the question. I would like to use the module as a directory path to run a py file via a command button in the GUI.